# Can't scrape website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i follow tutorial from [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe) about scraping website with Python and BeautifulSoup. I try to scraping website from my goverment (for research purpose) but it give me error like this :
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Python27/scrap web.py", line 8, in <module>
    name = name_box.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

i try another website like [this](http://www.chicagotribune.com/business/ct-nasa-spacex-rocket-elon-musk-20180505-story.html) and it work. And when i look into my goverment website and i use "View Page Source", i dont see code like `<table id="tableLeftBottom">`. So, how i can scrap data from this website ?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = "https://bps.go.id/linkTableDinamis/view/id/1116"
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

name_box = soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "tableRightBottom"})
name = name_box.text.strip()
print name
```

Comment: What are you trying to scrape off that page?

Comment: sorry, i just realize make some mistake on my code. I want to scrape table, as far as i know, on that website i need to scrap table with `id` `tableRightBottom`, `tableRightUp`, `tableLeftBottom`. After i scrape this website, i need to upload the data into mysql. But, at this time may be i just need to scrape the table first.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from that page you need to make a `post` request to this [url](https://bps.go.id/mod/Layout/variabelView.php) along with necessary parameters or you can try using any browser simulator. However, the first option is easy to go with. Here is how you can fetch the data using `post` request:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://bps.go.id/mod/Layout/variabelView.php"
payload = "valueDataSelect=**98+--+189+--+102+--+63+--+9818910263+--+1**98+--+190+--+102+--+63+--+9819010263+--+1**98+--+191+--+102+--+63+--+9819110263+--+1**98+--+189+--+105+--+63+--+9818910563+--+1**98+--+190+--+105+--+63+--+9819010563+--+1**98+--+191+--+105+--+63+--+9819110563+--+1**98+--+189+--+107+--+63+--+9818910763+--+1**98+--+190+--+107+--+63+--+9819010763+--+1**98+--+191+--+107+--+63+--+9819110763+--+1**98+--+189+--+108+--+63+--+9818910863+--+1**98+--+190+--+108+--+63+--+9819010863+--+1**98+--+191+--+108+--+63+--+9819110863+--+1**98+--+189+--+109+--+61+--+9818910961+--+1**98+--+190+--+109+--+61+--+9819010961+--+1**98+--+191+--+109+--+61+--+9819110961+--+1**98+--+189+--+110+--+61+--+9818911061+--+1**98+--+190+--+110+--+61+--+9819011061+--+1**98+--+191+--+110+--+61+--+9819111061+--+1**98+--+189+--+111+--+61+--+9818911161+--+1**98+--+189+--+111+--+62+--+9818911162+--+1**98+--+190+--+111+--+61+--+9819011161+--+1**98+--+190+--+111+--+62+--+9819011162+--+1**98+--+191+--+111+--+61+--+9819111161+--+1**98+--+191+--+111+--+62+--+9819111162+--+1**98+--+189+--+112+--+61+--+9818911261+--+1**98+--+189+--+112+--+62+--+9818911262+--+1**98+--+190+--+112+--+61+--+9819011261+--+1**98+--+190+--+112+--+62+--+9819011262+--+1**98+--+191+--+112+--+61+--+9819111261+--+1**98+--+191+--+112+--+62+--+9819111262+--+1**98+--+189+--+113+--+61+--+9818911361+--+1**98+--+189+--+113+--+62+--+9818911362+--+1**98+--+190+--+113+--+61+--+9819011361+--+1**98+--+190+--+113+--+62+--+9819011362+--+1**98+--+191+--+113+--+61+--+9819111361+--+1**98+--+191+--+113+--+62+--+9819111362+--+1**98+--+189+--+114+--+61+--+9818911461+--+1**98+--+189+--+114+--+62+--+9818911462+--+1**98+--+190+--+114+--+61+--+9819011461+--+1**98+--+190+--+114+--+62+--+9819011462+--+1**98+--+191+--+114+--+61+--+9819111461+--+1**98+--+191+--+114+--+62+--+9819111462+--+1**98+--+189+--+115+--+61+--+9818911561+--+1**98+--+189+--+115+--+62+--+9818911562+--+1**98+--+190+--+115+--+61+--+9819011561+--+1**98+--+190+--+115+--+62+--+9819011562+--+1**98+--+191+--+115+--+61+--+9819111561+--+1**98+--+191+--+115+--+62+--+9819111562+--+1**98+--+189+--+116+--+61+--+9818911661+--+1**98+--+189+--+116+--+62+--+9818911662+--+1**98+--+190+--+116+--+61+--+9819011661+--+1**98+--+190+--+116+--+62+--+9819011662+--+1**98+--+191+--+116+--+61+--+9819111661+--+1**98+--+191+--+116+--+62+--+9819111662+--+1**98+--+189+--+117+--+61+--+9818911761+--+1**98+--+189+--+117+--+62+--+9818911762+--+1**98+--+190+--+117+--+61+--+9819011761+--+1**98+--+190+--+117+--+62+--+9819011762+--+1**98+--+191+--+117+--+61+--+9819111761+--+1**98+--+191+--+117+--+62+--+9819111762+--+1&wilayahDataSelect=1%23%23~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9~10~11~12~13~14~15~16~17~18~19~20~21~22~23~24~25~26~27~28~29~30~31~32~33~34~35~1%40%40%24%24%24%40%40&keteranganDataSelect=**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2002+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2002+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2002+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2005+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2005+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2005+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2007+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2007+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2007+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2008+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2008+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2008+--+Tahunan**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2009+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2009+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2009+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2010+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2010+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2010+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2011+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2011+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2011+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2011+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2011+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2011+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2012+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2012+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2012+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2012+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2012+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2012+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2013+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2013+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2013+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2013+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2013+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2013+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2014+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2014+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2014+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2014+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2014+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2014+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2015+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2015+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2015+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2015+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2015+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2015+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2016+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2016+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2016+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2016+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2016+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2016+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2017+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan+--+2017+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2017+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perdesaan+--+2017+--+Semester+2+(September)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2017+--+Semester+1+(Maret)**Gini+Rasio++--+Perkotaan%2BPerdesaan+--+2017+--+Semester+2+(September)&kirim=3&layout=Var"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    html = s.post(URL, data = payload).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for items in soup.find(id="tableRightBottom").find_all("tr"):
        data = [item.text for item in items.find_all("td")]
        print(data)
```

Output:

```
[' - ', '0.332', '0.289', '0.301', '0.291', '0.312', '0.353', '0.370', '0.337', '0.407', '0.404', '0.382', '0.358', '0.380', '0.367', '0.368', '0.343', '0.362', '0.347', '0.334', ' - ', '0.239', '0.257', '0.253', '0.250', '0.261', '0.280', '0.269', '0.271', '0.260', '0.256', '0.254', '0.259', '0.277', '0.292', '0.293', '0.288', '0.296', '0.293', '0.299', ' - ', '0.288', '0.285', '0.290', '0.288', '0.301', '0.326', '0.326', '0.320', '0.341', '0.341', '0.331', '0.325', '0.337', '0.334', '0.339', '0.333', '0.341', '0.329', '0.329']
```

and so on ----

Comment: Hey! It is possible to target the csv download as that could then be uploaded to sql.

Comment: i'm sorry, where you get `payload` ?

Comment: Downloading the file is a bit tricky cause there is no url connected to it; rather, the download gets initiated via ajax call through `onclick` method. In that case selenium is your best bet. However, you don't need to download the file as the data can be written very easily in a csv file @QHarr.

Comment: Did you execute the script @Ade Guntoro? Didn't you get the result?

Comment: In chrome dev tools under network section there are few tabs. One of which is xhr. Click to select it and then reload the page. When the page is reloaded then you can find different urls doing different activity. Pick the right one responsible to fetch the result. When you click on that right url you can see a projected box includes more information related to it. Scroll the box downward and that is where you can find the `payload` information. Thanks.

Comment: @QHarr, check out this [forum link](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/handling-webpages-with-lazyload-in-an-efficient-way.38408/) where I've solved the problem related to lazyload.

Comment: @SIM Nice. I forgot I was going to look back at that question. I am totally going to put that in my toolbox and reference you of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the website html did not contain the data. The data is rendered by JavaScript inside the `div` with id `dataDynamic`. The data is from endpoint https://bps.go.id/mod/Layout/variabelView.php.

If you want to get the data, you can either use selenium or requests_html.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to find the node which is name "th" and id is "th2b".But these content is create by javascript.When you open the site,you will see that loading.So you should use "headless browser".

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gup")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.binary_location = "you chrome path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
response = driver.get(quote_page)
time.sleep(10)
page = response.get_body()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

name_box = soup.find("th", attrs={"id": "th2b"})
name = name_box.text.strip()
print(name)
```

you will get text.